# Flutter responsive layout by enclosing everything in a root widget / How to change all double values of descendant widgets using one root widget

Tags: flutter, responsive

I was writing my own responsive layouts like this:
Instead of writing **Normal code**

```
Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
Text("abc", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
```

I used a function responsiveSize()

```
Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(responsiveSize(10, context))),
Text("abc", style: TextStyle(fontSize: responsiveSize(20, context))),
```

and define the function responsiveSize() as

```
double responsiveSize(double number, BuildContext context){
  if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 450) {
    return number;
  } else {
    return number * 1.5;
  }
}
```

or something like this which I can easily change.

But the problem with this is that I have to wrap every double value in my code with the function responsiveSize(), which is very tedious. I am looking for a way to wrap all my widgets in one root widget, like wrapping my MaterialApp widget inside a ResponsiveSize widget:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveSize(
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and writing **Normal code** (as mentioned above, use double values as it is without wrapping them in a responsiveSize() function) and define ResponsiveSize widget in some way which I don't know. This way I can use responsive layout by just one widget and can easily remove the root ResponsiveSize widget if I don't want it later.

However this involves changing all double values in all descendant widgets of the ResponsiveSize widget, and this is something which I don't know how to do.

So, **I would like to know how I can change all double values of all descendant widgets of a root widget?** How should I define the root widget?

Comment: i think an easier approach will be to use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil).

Comment: @hiwa Your comment is useful, thank you. (although not a complete solution)

Answer (score 0):

The [LayoutBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYDVcriKjsw) widget might be what you're looking for.